# Is there a way to use a pipeline env var within the extendedChoice parameter?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using the extendedChoice plugin for my Jenkins pipeline. It fetches the s3 objects from the bucket and provides the list of values using a short Groovy script. The issue is that I need to parametrize the s3 bucket by using the corresponding variable defined within the pipeline's environment section. How can I do this?

So I tried a lot of different snippets to get the env vars though with no result.

```
import jenkins.model.*

// This will print out the requested var from the global Jenkins config.

def envVars = Jenkins.instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()[0].getEnvVars()
return envVars['S3_BUCKET']

// This will print out values from the env vars of the node itself where the Jenkins is running.

def env = System.getenv('S3_BUCKET')
return env

// This is what I have now
def domainsList = "aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket someRandomBucket --output text --delimiter /".execute() | 'cut -d / -f 1'.execute() | 'sed 1d'.execute()
domainsList.waitFor()

def output = domainsList.in.text
return output.split('COMMONPREFIXES')
```

```
// This is the Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
    DOMAIN_NAME = "${params.DOMAIN_NAME}"
    MODEL_VERSION = "${params.MODEL_VERSION}"
    S3_BUCKET = "someRandomBucket"
    }
    parameters {
      extendedChoice(
        bindings: '',
        defaultValue: '',
        description: '',
        descriptionPropertyValue: '',
        groovyClasspath: '',
        groovyScript: '''
        def domainsList = "aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket someRandomBucket --output text --delimiter /".execute() | 'cut -d / -f 1'.execute() | 'sed 1d'.execute()
        domainsList.waitFor()
        def output = domainsList.in.text
        return output.split('COMMONPREFIXES')
        ''',
        multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
        name: 'DOMAIN_NAME',
        quoteValue: false,
        saveJSONParameterToFile: false,
        type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        visibleItemCount: 10)
      choice(
        choices: ['a', 'b'],
        description: 'Select a model version for processing',
        name: 'MODEL_VERSION')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean workdir') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh "echo $S3_BUCKET"
                sh "echo $DOMAIN_NAME"
                sh "echo $MODEL_VERSION"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned above I need to substitue the someRandomBucket hardcode with the S3_BUCKET env var value in the groovy script within the extendedChoice parameter

**RESOLVED** - Environment variables can be injected particarly for the parameter via the Jenkins job UI